# Ag-Grid setRowData is not setting the data inside of the grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I have a grid that is working almost perfectly. I make selections in dropdowns to get a set of grid data back, which works great. I'm using a service to keep the values of all my selections and the data so when the user navigates back to the page they don't have to go through the whole process of retrieving data again. All values stick except the grid data.

My onGridReady() function is as follows:

```
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    if(this._forecastService.gridData.length > 0) {
      this.filterData();
      this.gridApi.redrawRows();
    } else {
      this.gridApi.showNoRowsOverlay();
    }
  }
```

The filterData function is as follows:

```
filterData() {
    let historyData = this._forecastService.gridData.filter(row => { 
      if(this._forecastService.history) {
        return row.Section === "History";
      }
    });

    let retailData = this._forecastService.gridData.filter(row => { 
      if(this._forecastService.retail) {
        return row.Section === "Retail";
      }
    });

    let volumeData = this._forecastService.gridData.filter(row => { 
      if(this._forecastService.volume) {
        return row.Section === "Volume";
      }
    });

    let nsiData = this._forecastService.gridData.filter(row => { 
      if(this._forecastService.nsi) {
        return row.Section === "NSI";
      }
    });

    let deadNetData = this._forecastService.gridData.filter(row => { 
      if(this._forecastService.deadNet) {
        return row.Section === "Dead NET";
      }
    });

    let executionData = this._forecastService.gridData.filter(row => { 
      if(this._forecastService.execution) {
        return row.Section === "Execution";
      }
    });

    this.filteredData = [...historyData, ...retailData, ...volumeData, ...nsiData, ...deadNetData, ...executionData];
    if(this.filteredData.length === 0 && this._forecastService.gridData.length > 0) {
      this.filteredData = [...this._forecastService.gridData];
    }

    this.gridApi.setRowData(this.filteredData);
  }
```

I've put browser breakpoints and stepped through the code. The data is there and it reaches the setRowData() just as I expect, except no data is displaying in the grid.

Comment: add a timeout of 500ms for setRowData, hope it works

Comment: any luck @CStreet

Comment: Nope, adding the timeout didn't work either :/ The only way I've gotten it to work is by actually recalling the data @NagaSaiA

Comment: No issues now right :)

Comment: I'm sorry what?

Comment: I mean no issues with ag grid setRowData right  or are you still facing any other issue with work around

Comment: It's working with calling the data again, but that's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: any console errors ?  can you add console log above setRowData with console.log(this.filteredData) and add break point and other option is to increase time of timeout just to make grid available and all the data available setTimeout(() => { this.gridApi.setRowData(this.filteredData);}, 1000)

Comment: Instead of redraw use refresh cells with data - var params = {
        force: isForceRefreshSelected()
    };
    gridOptions.api.refreshCells(params);

Comment: No console errors. The data is available and the timeout doesn't work. I tried refreshCells without the params you put and it didn't work either. The params variable you typed throws an error saying it can't find that isForceRefreshSelected() method

Comment: try replace isForceRefreshSelected with gridOptions.api.refreshCells( { force: true})

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/

Comment: Still not working

Comment: can you create sample stackblitz with simple service to replicate this issue